# How to force Java to use only 2 bytes per character for Unicode characters (eg. 'ł')?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-16

I am working on translating a hashing algorithm from C# to Java, and it requires using the byte array of the string. The problem is when working with characters like 'ł' & 'ą', Java converts these letters into 2 characters and thus giving me 4 bytes instead of 2 that I am expecting.

I tried using `string.codePointAt()` instead of `string.charAt()`, but it keeps on processing those letters as 2 characters instead of 1. I thought Java uses 16bit Unicode same as C# & VB but why does it require 4 bytes for this letters when C# & VB were able to convert these as 2 bytes.

C# and VB reads the bytes of 'ł' as: [66, 1] (code below)

```
 bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("ł");
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", bytes));
```

Java reads the bytes of 'ł' as: [-59, 0, 26, 32] (code below)

```
String str = "ł";
byte[] B = str.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(B));
```

I even tried using StandardCharsets too, but still same issue.

Is there a way for Java to process these letters as a single UTF-16 character instead of separating it into 2 characters?

PS: I cannot also refactor the algorithm since it is already in use, and it just had to be done in our new Java too.

PPS: I tried normalizing the string but there are still differences, character "æ" is read with [-26,0] when C# outputs [230,0] for the character

Comment: Can you show your code? Please give us a [mcve] such that we are able to observe the same. It might just be that you are using something wrong in your Java code.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post with my code.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Your Java installation is haunted, since there's no way that should produce 4 bytes.

Comment: I am using Amazon Corretto 8, is it possible that that version of java is the culprit?

Comment: What's the source file encoding that your Java compiler expects? Probably, that doesn't match your editor settings. As a wild guess, your editor might be set to UTF-8, and the compiler assumes some ISO-8859 variant. From your example, print "ł".length(). If it doesn't output a 1, the encoding settings are wrong.

Comment: Or replace the "ł" by "\u0142" and see if everything is okay then.

Comment: I followed your suggestion Ralf, it now works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you are looking for Unicode normalizations. This is outside encoding, it is just normalization, and you want the NFC (so composed character when available). Check e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence  But now that you have the correct terminology you can search for solution in this site more easily

Comment: In short: Unicode has various possibility to describe the same grapheme (same semantic): one preferring pre-composed characters (and with a predefined priority), or with base character, followed by combining characters. Some OS/keyboard may prefer one or the other. For hashing you should always normalize.

Comment: You are right Giacomo, I have tested with more characters like "æø", and experience the same issue as before. I'll read more on this Unicode normalizations. PS. I have deleted my answer. I'll add a new one once I have a full understanding of this topic.

Comment: Hi Giacomo, I tried normalizing the string but there are still differences. Java is still reading  [-26,0] from the character "æ" when it should be [230,0]. Do you have any suggestions on what I am missing?

Comment: `[26, 32]` is _UTF-16LE_ byte sequence for  `‚` _Single Low-9 Quotation Mark_ (U+201A). And signed byte `-26` is the same as unsigned `230`…

Comment: Java and C# BOTH use UTF-16 for their native strings. So in both C# and Java, Unicode codepoints U+0000..U+FFFF are stored in one `char`, and codepoints U+10000..U+10FFFF are stored in 2 `char`s. So if you have a working implementation in C#, an equivalent implementation in Java should work the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Java's internal character encoding is UTF-16BE, `String#codePointAt(int)` and `String#getBytes()` (with no supplied arguments) both use the default character encoding, which depends on the Java implementation and the platform it's on. You have the right idea to use `String.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"))`, but I recommend you use `String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)` instead.

The second issue with C# returning `[230,0]` while Java returns `[-26, 0]`: technically, they are the same, bit-wise. However, C#'s byte array holds unsigned bytes, while Java's array holds signed bytes. Even though both Java and C# gives the same byte pattern, if you **really** want to express a positive value, you could store them in a `short` array instead:

```java
        String str = "æ";

        byte[] byteArray = "æ".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
        short[] newByteArray = new short[byteArray.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
            byte c = byteArray[i];
            newByteArray[i] = (c >= 0) ? c : (short)(c + 256);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteArray));
        // => [-26, 0]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newByteArray));
        // => [230, 0]
```

FWIW, replacing `æ` with `ł` gives me `[66, 1]` both for the byte array and short array.

Although the code "converts" the array into unsigned "bytes", **I would advise against doing this if you can**, because the byte array gives the same pattern as C#, and promises the same number size.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the issue, as Ralf Kleberhoff have guessed, I wasn't using the proper file encoding that the Java compiler expects. My file was using UTF-16LE encoding so I just passed -encoding "UTF-16" when compiling the file.

```
javac -encoding "UTF-16" HashBrowns.java
```

Also, as Samuel Hunter had suggested, I converted the values to positive to make sure that I get the exact same values as I get with C# & VB6.

```
private int[] convertSignedBytesToUnsignedint(byte[] b)
{
    int[] intArr = new int[b.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        intArr[i] = b[i] & 0xff;
    }
    return intArr;
}
```

I am not sure on which code is more optimized, but I just wanted to post this here so I can share what worked with my situation.

Comment: No. UTF-16 doesn't guarantee that. Unicode (and so UTF-16) may have different ways to express the same grapheme (e.g. with combining sequences)